# How would I replace the text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I am trying to make it say Loading. and replace it with Loading.. then Loading... and then back to Loading. and keeps repeating while connecting to a page with selenium

So far, I have done this:

```py
import threading
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
import time
website_loaded = False
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = r"C:\Users\Username\Documents\Python\geckodriver.exe")
website = sys.argv[1:]
def loading():
    while website_loaded == False:
        sys.stdout.write("Loading.\r")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        sys.stdout.write("Loading..\r")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        sys.stdout.write("Loading...\r")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        continue

loading_thread = threading.Thread(target = loading, args = ())
loading_thread.start()

driver.get(website)

website_loaded = True
```

Instead, it does Loading. then Loading.. the Loading... and then it keeps Loading... but the white line that shows where you are typing in cmd moves to the first dot

Comment: If you want to remove some of the dots, you can write space over them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going back to the start of the line with `\r` doesn't remove what you have written in that line.

If you want to remove some of the dots, you can write space over them:

```
sys.stdout.write("Loading.  \r")
...
sys.stdout.write("Loading.. \r")
...
sys.stdout.write("Loading...\r")
```